# How to make a homomorphic preimage/payment hash with current lightning network / Bitcoin implementations?

Tags: lightning-network, script, cryptography, sha256, escrow

If I remember / understand it correctly by using the mechanisms from the scriptless scripts paper we could easily create homomorphic preimages / paymenthashes.

I think this would be a very desirable property (in combination with shamir secret sharing) for example to create trustless escrow services (and not only for payment decolleration)

As far as I understand SHA-256 - which is currently used for payment hashes - is not homomorphic. In fact it is not even supposed to be homomorphic.

Does anyone see any way to gain the onchain enforcable homomorphic property with the current setup / protocol for htlcs and Bitcoin script without the necessity to change to 2party ecdsa magic / scriptless scripts or schnorr?

I fear the answer would be it is impossible but I thought I would ask since I am still a beginner with low level cryptography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the current system, it seems impossible to do so. The most probable protocol change/update will be after activating BIP Schnorr, when we have the chance to move away from payment_hash/preimage and can go to payment_point/secret_scalar.

Once we achieved this htlc's can be exchanged by [adoptor signatures as described in this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLaRKlIqjjguCILECVRXqVhec6yaNYyeMT).

Those would obviously be additative since going from the group order to the group element is obviously a homemorphism so that we have `(r1 + r2)*G = r1*G + r2*G` where `ri = preimage` or `secret_scalar` and `ri*G1` = payment_point

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to bitcoin, but [IBM released a homomorphic encryption toolkit](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2020/06/ibm-releases-fully-homomorphic-encryption-toolkit-for-macos-and-ios-linux-and-android-coming-soon/) in June 2020.